# WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0 SSO Login to .net Application and then goto callbackurl

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I have Is 5.7.0 and a .net application login with SSO

I config my service provider :

[image]

then Configure SSO :

[image]

and then Write my code with c# for Login button :

[image]

And Result is :
I press login button and i go to IIS Login then I eneter username and password it goto claims page and I select claims and then goto this page:

[image]

**BUT I WANT IT GOTO MY CALLBACK URL . FOR EXAMPLE : http://localhost:49545/Home/ABout**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution:
you should check this checkbox.
and you can goto postbackurl :

[image]